# Problems using grep and sed in bash

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I'm extracting domains, subdomains and ips from a text file using:

```
grep -oE '[[:alnum:]]+[.][[:alnum:]_.-]+' "extra-domains.txt" | sed 's/www.//' | sort -u > outputfile.txt
```

And I'm using this bash to run it quicker as: `extract-domains.sh text-with-domains.txt`

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="$1"
while read LINE; do
  grep -oE '[[:alnum:]]+[.][[:alnum:]_.-]+' "$LINE" | sed 's/www.//' | sort -u > outputfile.txt
done < ${FILE}
```

but I keep getting multiple errors with "No such file or directory" when running the bash.

Can anyone give me a hand? Thanks.

Comment: Who/where does say that running in `bash` is _faster_ then running directly in `grep`?

Comment: Can you show us your input file rather than asking/claiming your solution is not working

Comment: Hi @Inian I'm trying to run it as: "extract-domains.sh extra-domains.txt" inside extra-domains.txt there is text with domains.txt

Comment: Why are you running a bash while loop in the first place? Just the standalone `grep` should be sufficient as your first piece of code

Comment: Thanks for the reply just trying to make it run using bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you wrote it, grep takes "$LINE" as a filename. Is that what it is supposed to do ?

edit : There is no point in making a while loop and reading your file line by line. It will be much slower. You should probably write you script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -oE '[[:alnum:]]+[.][[:alnum:]_.-]+' "$1" | 
    sed 's/www.//' | 
    sort -u
```

and call it :

```
extract-domains.sh "extra-domains.txt" > outputfile.txt
```

Comment: Hi @Camion I'm trying to run it as: "extract-domains.sh extra-domains.txt" inside extra-domains.txt there is text with domains.txt

Comment: Yes I think  "$LINE" is been taken as a filename. How can solve this?

Comment: What you pass to grep as second argument, should be a filename and you pass lines read from extra-domains.txt, which are probably no filenames. 

I'm not sure what you expected from making a script but I don't thing it can go quicker than your original command.

If you wan't to make a script, to have it stored on your disk, Then there was no point in making a while loop. just put your code in your script, optionally insert newlines after the pipes symbols for readability, and replace "extra-domains.txt" with "$1"

Comment: You never need grep+sed. You can probably do it in one sed command and if not then you can do it in one awk command. Without seeing any sample input/output we're just guessing though.